# Elasticsearch: Create alias for template satisfying particular condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Is it possible to define different aliases when defining an index template. The different aliases would refer to index names that meet certain criteria.

Example:

```
{
   "index_patterns":[
      "*employee_records*"
   ],
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":3
   },
   "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
         "dynamic_templates":[
            // Dynamic Mapping
         ]
      }
   },
   "aliases":{
      "employee_records":{}
   }
}
```

Lets assume we create multiple indexes e.g.

- science_dept_employee_records_2015
- science_dept_employee_records_2016
- maths_dept_employee_records_2015
- maths_dept_employee_records_2016

At the time of defining the index template, none of these indexes exist. The mapping would remain the same. I would like to define two aliases for the above scenario  `science_dept_employee_records` & `maths_dept_employee_records`.

One way I can think is to duplicate the index template such that there is an alias for

```
 "index_patterns":[
      "maths_dept_employee_records*"
 ]
```

and another alias for

```
 "index_patterns":[
      "science_dept_employee_records*"
 ]
```

However this would introduce a lot of duplicates across the multiple templates. Is there a more way concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use [multiple templates matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#multiple-templates) with ordering like below.

One template defines all the mappings and settings and has the lowest order (applied first):

```
{
   "index_patterns":[
      "*employee_records*"
   ],
   "order": 1,
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":3
   },
   "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
         "dynamic_templates":[
            // Dynamic Mapping
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Another template defines the alias for `maths_dept_employee` indices with a higher order and is applied next:

```
{
   "index_patterns":[
      "maths_dept_employee_records*"
   ],
   "order": 2,
   "aliases":{
      "maths_dept_employee_records":{}
   }
}
```

Same thing for `science_dept_employee` indices:

```
{
   "index_patterns":[
      "science_dept_employee_records*"
   ],
   "order": 2,
   "aliases":{
      "science_dept_employee_records":{}
   }
}
```

Comment: True. But how will aliases get mapped in that case? As I mentioned, I want the alias `science_dept_employee_records` to map only to `science_dept_employee_records*`. and similarly for maths. Using suggested will map all aliases to all indexes satisfying the pattern

Comment: Ahh!! using the The `order` attribute will help the overriding.. Great. Thanks.. I will try that

Comment: Yes.. It worked.. Thanks..I had already up-voted the answer... Looks like I forgot to mark it as "Accepted Solution".. Did that now